# Check for preceding nodes starting from a specific point in xml

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to create an xpath to find an element which doesn't have any 'p', 'li', or 'span' preceding elements under a common parent. For example I have this structure:

```
  <a>
    <div>
      <div/>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            </p>
          </div>
          <img/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ci/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
```

The node I'm interested in is the `<img>` element. So far I have this xpath:

```
count(/a/div[1]/div[position() = last()]//img[(count(preceding::*[name() = 'p' or name() = 'li' or name() = 'span']) = 0)]) > 0
```

I don't care if any of the unwanted elements are under /a/div[1]/div[1]/ only under /a/div[1]/div[2]. With that said, preceding won't work because it'll look under /a/div[1]/div[1] which I don't care for. The 'p' element in the above example can be in any number of divs.

EDIT:
I added the div containing the element `<ci/>`.

Comment: You can check if they are *siblings* of your selected node or any of its ancestors: `//img[ancestor-or-self::*[preceding-sibling::p or preceding-sibling::li or preceding-sibling::span]]` (or the *negation* of that)

Comment: @helderdarocha Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to come up with something that worked for my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using the following:

`count(/a/div[1]/div[position() = last()]//img[(count(preceding::*[(name() = 'p' or name() = 'li' or name() = 'span']) and ancestor::div[parent::div[parent::a] and descendant::ci]]) = 0)]) > 0`